# setting delimiter in awk script

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have data seperated by either "space" or "space followed by new line" or "new line". I am writing awk script to post-process it. How do I define FS in this case ?
This is what I have got so far

```
BEGIN {
print "This is post processed data";
RS="#";
FS="[ \n| |\n]";
}

{
print $2 $4 $6 ;
}
```

But it's not working. Can someone correct syntax here?

Comment: Could you please provide some example data and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

To specify alternatives in a regular expression, you need to enclose the list in parentheses: `(` `)`.

Hence your `FS` line should be:

```
FS="( \n| |\n)";
```

Brackets `[` `]` are used when defining character classes, e.g. all even digits: `[02468]`.

You were almost right.